# About iOS14 of PencilKit

Tags: ios14, xcode12, pencilkit

environment
・MacOS: 10.15.7
・Xcode: 12.1
・iOS: 14.1

I am trying to PencilKit and but I cannot show PKToolPicker. I set my code as below:

[image]

```
if let window = UIApplication.shared.windows.first {
    if let toolPicker = PKToolPicker.shared(for: window) {
        toolPicker.addObserver(canvas)
        toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvas)
        canvas.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

I get a warning here:

> 'shared(for:)' was deprecated in iOS 14.0: Create individual instances instead.

So I changed it like this

```
let toolPicker = PKToolPicker.init()
toolPicker.addObserver(canvas)
toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvas)
canvas.becomeFirstResponder()
```

[image]

After all the PKToolPicker is not displayed

[image]

I am aiming to display such PKToolPicker

Please give me advice

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved it like this

```
toolPicker.addObserver(canvas)
toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvas)
canvas.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Comment: couldn't see any difference between ur old code and new code. !! Can you please elaborate clearly so that it will be easy for others to understand.

Comment: @DayaKevin Add an individual instance of the toolPicker to the ViewController: ** let toolPicker = PKToolPicker.init() **

Comment: @vmanjz As per the guidelines, I've added individual instance of the tool picker. Still no luck. Please find my code on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68501442/ios-pencilkit-not-drawing-on-the-pkcanvasview

Comment: @DayaKevin Instead of declaring a constant toolPicker in the function, declare it just below the IBOutlet near the top! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

First declare an individual instance of the toolPicker for the ***ViewController*** at the class level. This is required to be able to change pens in the toolPicker:

```
let toolPicker = PKToolPicker()
```

Then later, in viewWillAppear(_ :)

```
toolPicker.addObserver(canvas)
toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvas)
canvas.becomeFirstResponder()
```